# How can I connect to PPPOE over Wifi? (English/Español)

Tags: wireless, pppoe

In English*:

Hello good start this topic because I have a big problem in Ubuntu 11.04, I realize that does not support PPPOE Wifi my Wifi connection uses double dialing to connect to Wifi as I have to log into my account, and Ubuntu PPPOE does not support that kind of connection. It would be good to add support for that.

To be clear, I do not speak English well, because I do not understand much of it (my native language is Spanish).

*En Español:
Hola bueno inicio este tema porque tengo un gran problema en ubuntu 11.04, me doy cuenta que no tiene soporte para wifi pppoe, mi conexion wifi usa doble marcado osea para conectarme al wifi igual tengo que conectarme a mi cuenta pppoe y ubuntu o cualquier distrobucion de linux no tiene soporte para ese tipo de conexion 
seria bueno que agregaran soporte para eso, aclaro que yo no ablo en ingles por si no me entienden mucho mi idioma nativo es el español.*

* Please answer in English.

Comment: Traté de traducir y corregir lo que pude para usted.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100489/how-to-connect-to-broadband-connection/100491#100491

Comment: por favor, mire

Answer (score 1):

In English, courtesy of [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#auto%7Cen%7Cconectate%20a%20la%20red%20wifi%20que%20utilises%20luego%20escribe%20enuna%20terminal%20sudo%20pppoeconf%20luego%20dale%20que%20si%20a%20todo%20lo%20que%20te%20de%20cuando%20te%20pida%20la%20interface%20de%20red%20por%20la%20que%20se%20conecta%20elige%20la%20del%20wifi%20generalmente%20es%20wlan0,%20luego%20usuario%20y%20contrase%C3%B1a%20avituales%20y%20listo%20te%20dala%20unas%20lineas%20para%20iniciar%20y%20parar%20la%20coneccion%20copialo%20y%20guardalo%20ya%20que%20te%20servira%20luego%20para%20iniciarlo%0A%0APD%3a%20recuerda%20siempre%20conectarte%20primero%20a%20la%20red%20wifi%0A):

login to the wifi network that utilises terminal then type sudo pppoeconf ina then give that if all of you when you ask the network interface that connects the wifi chooses is usually wlan0, then username and password avituales and ready dala you a few lines to start and stop copy it and save the connection as it will then serve to start

PS: always remember to first connect to the wifi network

Spanish, original response:

conectate a la red wifi que utilises 
luego escribe enuna terminal        `sudo pppoeconf`
luego dale que si a todo lo que te de cuando te pida la interface de red por la que se conecta elige la del wifi generalmente es wlan0, luego usuario y contraseña avituales y listo te dala unas lineas para iniciar y parar la coneccion copialo y guardalo ya que te servira luego para iniciarlo

PD: recuerda siempre conectarte primero a la red wifi