# How to set up a broadband connection

Tags: 12.04, networking, broadband

I have a bsnl broadband connection. I don't see any settings for broadband in Ubuntu, and I can't just connect automatically -- "wired connections" shows no connection.  I see an option for mobile settings, but that doesn't work for this case.  Where do I need to look to get the broadband connection to work?

Comment: This has generated a great answer, so I wish there was confirmation of whether it worked.  Presumably, bsnl is an Indian ISP, but I can't access the company site.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The Click On Edit Connection > DSL > ADD
[image]
[image]
[image]

--------------------------------------OR--------------------------------------

1. Connect your ethernet wire to the port at the back of your computer.
2. Fire up the terminal and type in sudo pppoeconf
3. It should detect your modem.
4. Keep on pressing enter. Fill in your user name and password when indicated.
5. It should be easy to stick on to defaults.
6. You should be prompted back to your terminal when it would say pppoe loaded. Simple. That's the end of terminal.
   Now go to System>Networking. Click on it
7. Activate the Wired connection.
8. Highlight the wired connection and click on properties.
9. Check the box "enable the connection"

Comment: http://www.indiabroadband.net/linux/10828-how-configure-bsnl-broadband-connection-ubuntu.html

Comment: http://www.techomag.com/how-to-connect-the-bsnl-modem-in-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: http://www.etalkindia.com/talk/computer-software-troubleshooting/1783-how-connect-bsnl-internet-ubuntu-linux-broadband.html

Comment: Nice answer -- I'd recommend going ahead and putting the links into your answer, though, if you think they are sufficiently helpful or relevant.  If they age out, you or we can edit them.  This is harder to do with comments.

Answer (score 3):

Actually in my case it was still simpler : Right-click the network icon on the menu bar, click "Edit Connections", in the dialogue box that comes up click the "Add" tab, which will lead to another dialogue box, click open the low-down, choose "DSL", click "Create". In the next dialogue box type in your User Name, Service  Name and your Password and click "Save". Go back to the network icon on the menu bar and click "DSL connection". Done.