# How can I set up a broadband connection?

Tags: broadband

I tried to set up broadband Internet connection, started as I found [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100489/how-to-set-up-a-broadband-connection)

```
sudo pppoeconf
```

and shown that wifi was disabled.

> Sorry, I scanned 2 interfaces, but the Access
>   Concentrator of your provider did not respond. Please
>   check your network and modem cables. Another reason for
>   the scan failure may also be another running pppoe
>   process which controls the modem.

and the result found below my command was

```
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

If the same command runs after enabling wifi, no result is showing in terminal.

Then I tried another command

```
sudo ifconfig
```

And got this result:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:89:84:ea:68:5d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8947 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8947 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:961374 (961.3 KB)  TX bytes:961374 (961.3 KB)


wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:d2:24:3f:4f:3e  
          inet addr:192.168.59.104  Bcast:192.168.59.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4ad2:24ff:fe3f:4f3e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:241942 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:173747 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:338342037 (338.3 MB)  TX bytes:18314966 (18.3 MB)
```

Can anyone please explain to me what the is problem and what steps I should follow to resolve it?

Comment: Have you setup your modem(the instructions should be in the manual for the modem)?

Comment: Can you (on another computer) go to google and search `my ip` and then copy and paste that into the url bar, and see what is displayed. I think it will be your router configuration page. Do you see this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting up for BSNL, Network Manager does not support PPP connection over WiFi as of now. [And it probably never will.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/232172)

You need to edit a file and then run a command to start a connection.
Edit `/etc/ppp/peers/provider` and add these lines:

```
plugin rp-pppoe
wlan1

user "username"
noipdefault

usepeerdns
defaultroute
replacedefaultroute
noauth
persist
hide-password
```

You must replace `wlan1` with the name of your wireless interface. Use the `iwconfig` command to find out. In your case it could be `wlan0`. Replace `"username"` (keep the quotes here) with your login username provided by the ISP.
Then edit `/etc/ppp/chap_secrets`:

```
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client    server  secret          IP addresses
username *      password
```

Again, replace `username` and `password` with login details from your ISP (no quotes here).

If you're unsure of how to edit them, use `sudo -H gedit <filename>` to edit both files.

Then use the command `pon` to start a connection and `poff -a` to stop all connections when you're done. Use `plog` to check the status of the connection.

---

If you are using Network Manager to connect to WiFi, you can get it to start a connection automatically when the WiFi is connected. In a terminal, type:

```
sudo grep -i uuid /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
```

You will see a list of files with UUIDs listed. Copy the UUID for your WiFi connection (e.g. `44f15a85-2c11-453d-b557-385ba3a5bb84`). Do `sudo  -H gedit /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/10-ppp.sh` and add these lines:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ $CONNECTION_UUID == '44f15a85-2c11-453d-b557-385ba3a5bb84' ]]
then
    case $1 in
    up)
        while pgrep ppp >/dev/null
        do 
            poff -a
        done
        pon
        ;;
    down)
        while pgrep ppp >/dev/null
        do 
            poff -a
        done
        ;;
    *)
    ;;
    esac
fi
```

After saving the file, execute these commands:

```
sudo chown root /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/10-ppp.sh
sudo chmod 744 /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/10-ppp.sh
```

You have to do this because dispatcher scripts have to be owned by `root` and not writable by anybody else but the owner, and should be executable.

Here's the annoying bit: If the Wireless connection goes down suddenly, when it gets reconnected, `ppp` won't be able to reconnect for a couple of minutes or more. You may even have to restart `ppp` manually by doing `poff -a; pon` a couple of times. You'll know the connection has been established when `plog` shows the IP address you have been assigned.