# What is the default root password and how to setup pppoe

Tags: root, pppoe

1. The installation didn't ask me to set root password, but many occasions asked me for it.
   So what's the default root password?
2. I wish to connect to network via PPPoE. How do I set it up?

Comment: There is no default root password: http://askubuntu.com/questions/189907/what-is-the-default-root-password
For PPP over Wifi, have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/486655/how-can-i-set-up-a-broadband-connection/486706#486706
PPPoE is easily set up using Network Manager (by setting up a DSL connection).
Please do not ask multiple unrelated questions in the same post. Split up your question into as many independent questions as you need.

Comment: when do you get asked for a root password?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no default root password in Ubuntu. The root account is locked by design and administrative tasks are done by `sudo` command.
2. See the Network Manager - click the Network Manager icon in the upper-right corner and select "Edit Connections".

Answer (score 0):

If you want set a root password :

```
sudo passwd root
```

enter your sudo user password, and after chose your root password.

If you want login in root :

```
su
```