# Not able to connect to internet in ubuntu after changing modem settings

Tags: networking, pppoe

I used to connect from broadband connection in ubuntu as shown in

[How to set up a broadband connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100489/how-to-set-up-a-broadband-connection)

but then I did some changes in modem as shown in

http://www.ashout.com/error-651-with-pppoe-connections-in-windows-7-fix/

after that I am not able to connect despite making changes.Although in windows it works fine since am able to connect to internet without making connection.

I also tried the changes mentioned in the given link but it did not help much

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-networking-configuration-using-command-line.html

when typing `sudo ifconfig`

[image]

and when I opened and changed gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces and restarted the networking,yet it did not connect!

[image]

please help!

Comment: Please send screenshots from your machine because the picture files attached are barely readable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't visited the links you provided yet (I will)... but for now, try this:

`sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid (network name) key (password)`

*replace "network name" with the network name to which you wish to connect and "password" with that network's password

`sudo dhclient wlan0`

Also make sure your adapter isn't down by RF-KILL or anything crazy like that!